# How would you implement twitter using a noSQL kind of DB?

Tags: database-design, caching, twitter, nosql

It seems like implementing web-app like twitter/facebook-wall needs 1 huge "feeds" relational table (+ a user table)
and an awesome caching mechanism.. ( can you recommend one? )

my main question is, how would you implement such a "feature" using a non-relational DB, e.g. a key/value kind of DB?

Obviously, I had like to support the amount of users using twitter concurrently and in general.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is highly dependent on exact DB type

Comment: Twitter is using MySQL to store the tweets: http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/cassandra-at-twitter-today.html

Comment: my question is not how twitter implemented their solution, but how would you implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read how twitter did it over here: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/2/19/twitters-plan-to-analyze-100-billion-tweets.html

Also read this: http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster

No data models but quite a lot of information about how ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Redis. Queue of keys per user + set of blobs retrieved by these keys.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a minimal implementation of twitter data layer using HBase. If you are interested you can have a look at the gist : https://gist.github.com/1101316 . The first file CreateTwitterTable.java has the code to create the hbase tables and their related column families. The second file TwitterClient.java has the code for the basic functions such has getTimeline, addTweet, deleteTweet, followUser, unfollowUser and addUser.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw MongoDB into the list.

Schema is going to be pretty simple.

TWEETS
UserName (or a UserID if want to normalize a bit)
TweetID (a unique number)
Timestamp
Tweet (text of tweet)

USER
UserID (optional) 
UserName
Name, Email, Personal info (web url, etc) 
Password (hash)
Followers (repeating user ref)
Following (repeating user ref)

Comment: ok, how do you query efficiently for all the tweets of the people that one is following

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Kestrel, the message queue system that Twitter uses

http://github.com/robey/kestrel

http://www.google.com/search?q=kestrel+twitter

Answer (score -1):

> Obviously, I had like to support the
>   amount of users using twitter
>   concurrently and in general.

Sorry but this requirement is far away from being realistic. Twitter has a huge server farm to shard the data for supporting their massive concurrency, do you have as much servers as twitter?

There is an architectural idea implementing a twitter clone with redis:
[TwitterAlikeExample](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/TwitterAlikeExample)

Comment: for the redis architecture: add sharding and replication as twitter does.